# phpStorm, do not index a folder / tree

Tags: php, deployment, ide, phpstorm

I can't find the ability of phpStorm 5 to avoid indexing a specific folder. I don't want to exclude it from the Project-View, just don't want phpStorm to index the containing folders, classes, functions etc.

How is that possible?

Comment: This sounds more like a google request than a real question, see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5279592

Comment: Agreed with above comment, see also http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537.

Comment: still, google got me here and I was about to ask a similar question. At least with the same outcome

Comment: on-topic: `software tools commonly used by programmers`. moreso since phpstorm, webstorm, pycharm and intellij all usually have very similar interfaces, behaviors, problems and solutions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From their documentation, looks like the only way to achieve this is to Exclude the directory which will hide it from the project tree...

[PhpStorm Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html)

> To have PhpStorm ignore the selected directory during indexing, parsing, code completion, etc., click the Excluded toolbar button  or choose Excluded on the context menu of the selection.

Comment: Well, how to just exlude for indexing, but I want to see this folder in project's tree?

Comment: @Sergey you can't, that's my point

Comment: It's very annoying (((

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168293/phpstorm-exclude-files-by-mask-from-indexing a middle ground solution...

Comment: You can mark the folder as Resource first, then Excluded. Now it will not be indexed but it will show in the Project tree.

Comment: in 8.* versions, excluding (from indexing, etc.) the directory is OK, and you can still see it on the folder tree. Works like a charm.

Comment: ok... how to make it visible again..? jesus christ.

Comment: @Becario https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html#d1068792e323