# PHPStorm exclude files by mask from indexing

Tags: phpstorm

I'm having a PHP project that for some reason (not my initiative) has some backup files like "somefile - backup.php".
How do I exclude "%backup%.php" from indexing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types | Ignore files and folders` field on the bottom -- add `*-backup.php` pattern (or whatever pattern you need).

**PLEASE NOTE:** this affects **all** projects as it is an IDE-wide setting.

[image]

---

**Alternatively** (have not tried myself, but should work):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types | Recognized File Types | Text`

Add `*-backup.php` pattern there.

This will also affect all projects .. but instead of excluding it will treat them as plain text files, so no indexing/code completion/syntax highlighting/etc while still having such files in the Project View tree (so you can edit/delete/upload/etc them if necessary).

Comment: The second alternative is perfect if you want to avoid using scopes. Thank you. For Symfony2 users add `app*.php` (lowercase) and `classes.php` to the file patterns that should be recognized as text files. As it doesn't seem to allow regular expressions this will also un-index your `app.php` and `app_dev.php` but as they are normally edited just once I think that drawback is worth it.

Comment: @MohammedSaqibRajput Mark it as Excluded.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanx. Right click the directory -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded.

Comment: The first setting only affects version control and has moved to `Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files` or `Settings | Version Control | Ignore Files Support` and the second setting is now under `Settings | Editor | File Types`.

Comment: @TwoD The settings did not move anywhere under Version Control -- it's still there. Just new settings path since v9 -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`. Version Control settings is different/separate stuff.

Comment: @LazyOne v9? I'm using PhpStorm 2016.3 and those settings are nowhere to be seen. There's also no `Preferences`, just `Settings` and `Default Settings` under `File`.

Comment: @TwoD **1)** `Preferences` is for Mac users ... which do not have `File | Settings` .. because it's `PhpStorm | Preferences` on Mac; therefore `Settings/Preferences` is whatever you have got there **2)** It is there -- 100% -- http://postimg.org/image/stox8ep55/ ; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/file-types.html

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, got that. Never mind about the missing settings, I thought you meant the original location was still there.

Answer (score 5):

"Settings > File Types > Ignore file and folders" and add the path of the folder.

Example: `*.lib;client/build;`

This worked for me to ignore a folder.