# how to exclude files from webstorm with a pattern

Tags: meteor, webstorm

with webstorm you can manually click on files/directories to exclude them, one-by-one.
but where are these settings saved?

is there a way to add a pattern, eg exclude  `packages/*/.build/*`  ?

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26227363/586086?

Comment: happy halloween andrew *) I couldn't find that setting in webstorm. but theres a config file in .idea/$PROJECT.iml which you can add strings to. it doesn't seem to respect wildcards, but at least you can just paste the output of an ls there...

Comment: *"I couldn't find that setting in webstorm"* Settings screen has search functionality (top left corner) -- you do not know what such field is for and what it can do?

Answer (score 1):

Excluded folders are written to `.idea/<project_name>.iml` file in the following format:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/path1" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/path2" />
...
</content>
```

Patterns/wildcards are not supported

Comment: thanks, that's what i just added in the comment above!